# Laravel - Filter morphOne or hasOne relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have three models related by a `morph` relationship.

`Shipment` can have multiple `Status` instances, through a `StatusHistory` class.

```
    class Status extends Model {
       //id, name
    }

    class Shipment extends Model {
       public function latestStatus() {
          return $this->morphOne('App\StatusHistory', 'model')->latest();
       }
    }

    class StatusHistory extends Model {
       public function model() {
            return $this->morphTo();
        }

        public function status() {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Status', 'status_id');
        }
    }
```

I want to get all `Shipment` entities where the `latestStatus` has a specific `Status` name value.

```
   Shipment::whereHas('latestStatus', function($query) {
      return $query->whereHas('status', function($query) {
         return $query->where('name', 'reserved');
      });
   })->get();
```

This is not working and returns all entities that have a status of 'reserved', even though the `latestStatus` can be something else.

Any thoughts?

EDIT (added sample information):

I have 2 shipments.

1. The first one has only one status history instance with 'reserved' in its status name.
2. The second one has two status history instances with 'reserved' and 'shipped' in its status name. The status history instance for 'shipped' is created LATER than 'reserver'.

So:

1. The first shipment has last status of 'reserved'.
2. The second shipment has last status of 'shipped'.

The call should only return the first shipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is getting all shipments and filtering them afterwards:

```php
Shipment::with('latestStatus.status')->get()->where('latestStatus.status.name', 'reserved')
```

Depending on your database size this might not be very efficient.

A query that only fetches the relevant shipments:

```php
Shipment::select('shipments.*')
    ->join('status_histories as sh', 'shipments.id', 'sh.model_id')
    ->join('statuses as st', 'sh.status_id', 'st.id')
    ->where('model_type', Shipment::class)
    ->where('st.name', 'reserved')
    ->where('created_at', function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('MAX(created_at)')
            ->from('status_histories')
            ->where('model_id', DB::raw('sh.model_id'))
            ->where('model_type', DB::raw('sh.model_type'));
    })->get();
```

Comment: I get `Unknown column 'latestStatus.status.name' `

Comment: Did you move `->get()` to the end?

Comment: You can't move it to the end. The query has to stay the way I posted it.

Comment: But it's hard on the database since there could lot of status history instances. If those grow the query will grow in time as well.

Comment: I'll write the more efficient query. Is there a `BelongsTo` relationship between `StatusHistory` and `Status`?

Comment: I just tested this but it's returning all rows from Shipment. If a shipment has a 'reserved' status history and also another one 'shipped' for example, it's also returning that shipment, even though the latest status is 'shipped'.

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question where the problems occur?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168150/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-felipe-pena).